# How can I change the linebreaks from a multiline textbox to HTML <br /> tags?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Im working on a bulk email sending app and have a page with a multiline textbox which I am wanting to use as a way of allowing a user to enter the email body text.

I need to format the text within my textbox to HTML, most importantly I need to format linebreaks to HTML, however I cant seem to do this.

The method everyone seems to say to use is:

```
textOut.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

But this just does nothing.  My Textbox looks like this:

```
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" 
                            ID="txtMailBody" 
                            TextMode="MultiLine" 
                            Width="650" 
                            Height="150"/>
```

When I enter text in the textbox such as:

```
Line 1

Line 2
Line 3
```

It always outputs like

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
txtMailBody.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, tried that too but it doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: just tried this one and it works as it should. what's your output then?

Comment: It always outputs as I posted in the question, just on a single line rather than new lines or with HTML, I even tried response.write() to see what is in the variables before and after I try the replaces but it just comes back on one line.

Comment: I tried with Response.Write(txtMulti.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
What happens with the textbox content before you do the replace? is there anyting else which may change the content?

Comment: Weirdly this works, the way I was doing it was to pass the textbox.text as a parameter into my format method which doesnt work, however if i just do the replace and assign it to the body of my mail message it works fine.... Im guessing its something to do with the text being assigned to string etc. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

Alle three lines below do it:

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbLf, "<br>" + vbCrLf)

TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br>" + vbCrLf)

TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbNewLine, "<br>" + vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txtMailBody.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />")
```

This may help you fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It worked when I used the following code:

```
textOut.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a function in php named as nl2br you can search for an asp alternative to it.